# Android Geofencing PendingIntent not firing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geofencing, android-geofence

I have a GeofenceImplementorClass. I'm adding three geofences in it, one of which is my current location that I got from `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);`. I'm expecting the IntentClass service to get executed as I am already at one of the geofence locations however the service is not getting executed. Please help.

```
public class GeofenceImplementor implements ResultCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private ArrayList<Geofence> geofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Boolean isConnected = false;
    private Boolean request = false;
    private Context context;

    public GeofenceImplementor(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void addToList(LatLng latLng,String key){
        geofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(key)
                .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1000)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build());
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(geofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(){
        if(pendingIntent != null)
            return  pendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,IntentClass.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public void implement() {
        if(isConnected) {
            try {
                LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient,
                        getGeofencingRequest(), getPendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                Log.e("Security Exception", ex.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
        else request = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current location radius was greater than the geofence.
Increasing the Geofence circle radius to 3000m solved the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by "current location radius"?

Comment: The radius of the circle that appears around your present location on your device.